windows 11 scrolling issue
I am having a really annoying problem where in several (but not all) applications, when I scroll anything (a view pane, a document, actively scrolling with a scrollbar, changing the zoom etc) using my mouse scroll wheel, windows takes it upon itself to automatically reverse my scrolling action.
Examples of where scrolling behaves:

Inside this textbox I'm typing in right now.

Example of where it doesn't behave:

opening an image in msoft paint and scrolling for any reason at all, including zooming in/out: scrolls way past and doesn't stop. (also, all of a sudden, the CTRL key is controlling zoom by itself, not in conjunction with mouse wheel. Pretty sure it never used to do that before?). So now CTRL+A, CTRL+C etc are being interrupted with a zoom-in so keypresses have to be very fast now to stand a chance of effecting select all and copy, respectively.

Behavior
The automatic reverse scroll kicks in almost as soon as I start scrolling and "fights me" as I try to finish scrolling in the desired direction. And not just reversing the scroll action, but reversing it all the way to the beginning of a document, view or zoom control. I.e. once it starts reversing my scroll action, it doesn't stop until the point where it is not possible to scroll any further in that opposite direction. It's crazy-making.
Things I tried

3 different mice, to no avail (all are usb mice) so I don't think it's a device issue but a windows issue.
System restore (tho, I couldn't find any restore points to before I started noticing this issue). unresolved.
Re-applied outstanding windows updates: things got better in some instances but scrolling is still messed up in a lot of places.

How can I fix this?
I don't trust using malwarebytes or whatever (if this is a virus) as I'm pretty sure this started after downloading their software and doing a sweep (in which I noticed way after the fact, that it disabled windows defender in order to do its job, so who knows what got into the system after that point).
System info
It's a custom built desktop pc.



Windows has implemented reverse mouse and touchpad scrolling (as have other operating systems, such as Linux). This can be turned on or off through a setting.

Press Windows, type "mouse,"  and select Mouse & Touchpad.
On the Mouse tab, select the scrolling direction you prefer.


You might be fighting the touchpad, depending on your PC make and model (information which should be included within the question). There might be additional mouse and touchpad options, such as shown below, to turn off the touchpad.


Look for a control panel for your specific hardware, e.g., ALPS, Elan, Synaptics, etc. See if there is a setting to control scrolling in that CPL, as well.

Some of the drivers for these devices might not be Windows 11 compatible. For example, drivers for the ALPS touchpad on older Dell laptops are not available for Windows 10, much less 11. It might be possible to uninstall the driver, using the generic Windows driver, instead... though after a reboot, the ALPS driver might be reinstalled.

Some applications implement continuous scrolling. For example, in the screenshot below, the symbol ↕ is shown overlaid on the page because the middle mouse button was pressed. Moving the mouse above the cursor causes the page to scroll down, and vice versa.




I don't even have  a "device settings" tab in my Mouse Properties dialog box.

That additional tab is from a touchpad driver. If you have a laptop, those settings may be in Mouse Properties or in a separate dialog. As mentioned, it depends on PC make and model, which should be in the question -- please edit it.

added system info to the post.
